# php pdf download - can't open the downloaded file correctly

Tags: php, pdf, download

On my webpage is the possibilty to download a pdf-file (285kB). The problem is that you download the website as a pdf and not the pdf-file I want to be downloaded.

So I'cant open the downloaded pdf with Adobe Reader but have to open the file with notepad and the content is

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><he...
```

Here is the Code for downloading the file:

```
 $filepath = "/download/";
    $filename = "filename";
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream' );
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filepath.$filename));
    readfile($filepath.$filename);
    exit;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `Content-Type` header. Use

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf' );
```

It is defined in [RFC 3778](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778)

Comment: Are you sure that `$filename` contains a path to a valid pdf file?

Comment: Yes I am. I already tried it without a path and put the pdf in the main-directory... --> same problem

Comment: Show the html of the download link

Comment: Can I ask you to follow the comments from Jospeh118 and me? There are some more information written :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment because of my low reputation. That is why posting as answer. You could try with

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf' );
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

did you add the extension with the file name? like this...

```
$filename = "filename.pdf";
$filepath = "/download/".$filename;

if (file_exists($filePath) {
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
header('Content-type: application/zip' );
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filePath));
readfile($filepath);
exit;
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this script?

Comment: This small script ist on the same page where you can download the file. After clicking on the "download" -Submit-button the samy page will be opened again.
There is just an if-statement at the beginning which says:
if(isset($_POST['download']))

Comment: how are you sending the data? provide us with that

Comment: also provide us with a hierarchy of your directory.. your path might be wrong

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: well if your file is being downloaded but has no extension that means you just need to add the extension with the file name if not.. your path is wrong

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.
Maybe I just explain the hole szenario:
I have one webpage www.example.com/download and there is just one button download in a form-tag: <form method="post" action="www.example.com/download"> . 
So the same site will open again. There is just this one if-statement at the very beginning of this site: if(isset($_POST['download']))

Comment: okay, sorry. The extension is right but the content is wrong. If I want to open the File with Adobe Reader it says https://patrickhoban.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/error.png%3Fw%3D595

Comment: try my new edited answer, it checks if file_exists before download